# AWS - Optimize WAN link between VPCs

Tags: amazon-web-services, wide-area-network

I have 2 VPCs, one in us-east-1 and another in ap-northeast-1, with an OpenVPN tunnel between them.

According to my ping test, the latency between the two regions is ~160-180ms. Assuming all services (DB, caching, queue/workers, etc) must remain in US, while only web servers will be deployed to JP. There will be a huge delay accessing those services in US by JP web servers.

There are "WAN optimization/acceleration" products in the AWS marketplace. But i cant seem to find much info from google.

1. [Silver Peak](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00DGEXOT6/ref=srh_res_product_title?ie=UTF8&sr=0-5&qid=1405269489291)

   - I am forced to "enjoy" a 30-day free trial after accepting the terms.. I launched one in US, and another one in JP, and then tried to connect them into a tunnel...it then complained about duplicated license key because the trial keys are the same in both instances...
2. [CloudOpt](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B0090U6K82/ref=srh_res_product_title?ie=UTF8&sr=0-2&qid=1405269671339)

   - completely no idea how to set it up after launching into both regions. The UI is horrible, as well as their kb.
3. [CloudBridge](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00AAQ7UHA/ref=srh_res_product_title?ie=UTF8&sr=0-4&qid=1405269736457)

   - thought this will be much better because it si from a big name. but in the first step of the Get Started wizard, it just keep saying my AWS credential is incorrect and wont let me get passed.

Anyone has experience on optimizing the WAN link between VPCs? I am not sure if I am on the right track, is there any other ways to achieve the same thing (reduce latency and ensure good enough network speed between regions)?

Comment: Don't know if you already considered and ruled that out, but aws directconnect has connections both at US East (Virginia) and Asia Pacific (Tokyo) - using Equinix DC# and Equinix TY2 datacenters for example. Did you test latencies between equinix datacenters? also see directconnect faq: http://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/faqs/

Comment: I did look into Direct COnnect but I am not sure if it supports VPC-to-VPC connection?

Comment: I am asking for recommendation on optimizing the WAN link between VPCs, not asking for which wan optimizer to choose from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your OpenVPN tunnel isn't adding significantly to the round-trip-time (RTT) of the link when compared to the RTT between the sites without OpenVPN, there is no technology that can actually reduce the actual RTT below that of the underlying links.

You're limited by the laws of physics (the propagation delay of signals through wire and fiber optic cables, and possibly to a satellite and back, though the latter seems unlikely or the RTT would be even worse) and by the speed at which the intermediate routers within and between the regions can switch packets.

Using extremely round numbers (7,000 miles x 2, at 2/3 of the speed of light in a vacuum) I would say ~113ms of your delay is simply the best-case time for light to travel from one place to the other and back again. Nothing can eliminate that.

Compression, analogous to packing more passengers on an airplane, or flying larger planes, gets more data across a link of a given capacity per unit of time, but no single passenger spends any less time in transit.

Caching, in its various forms, also can give the convenient illusion of faster data retrieval, but uncached data can't arrive any faster than normal.

If OpenVPN isn't adding any appreciable additional latency (and in my experience, it shouldn't be) then you aren't going to find a magic bullet solution.

Your application's architecture will likely have to adapt to accommodate this essentially fundamental delay, including database read replicas, local queues (possibly even for handling the eventual execution of non-critical database writes), and more efficient database access.

Answer (score 2):

All WAN optimization products are caches. Knowing that why not just deploy standard caches, like memcached, mysql/percona slave servers, nginix/varnish to the Japan VPC? I'd really look behind the scenes into the WAN optimization products you were deploying, they probably just leverage this types of caches in a pretty package.

Comment: afaik they also compress the data before sending. BTW, we use elasticache which does not allow cross-region, and it's hard to keep Memcached data in different instances in sync. Even if we have a RDS read replica in JP, DB still need to go to US.

Comment: I mean DB writes.

Comment: Still if you have WAN optimization in the Japan, it is a cache in the DC. And worse it is a black box which may be harder to implement in a secure and auditable fashion.